# Vuejs - How to insert JS Tracking Codes like Google Analytics or Adsense

Tags: vue.js, frontend, single-page-application, vuejs2

So I am developing a site as a SPA with Vue JS and I have just came across a issue.

I went to insert Adsense's code snippet like i would normally, but Vue complains with the following

- Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed.

So I am now a bit stuck, I have seen a library that will put Adsense in as a component but its a very new/small library and i could not get the thing to work.

I also have a lot of other tracking pixels that will need to go on the site in a similar fashion so I will need to find a way around doing this.

Can anyone lend some advise, thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code snippet where you inserted  Adsense's code snippet?

Comment: The same issue was created before [#5264](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5264), but was closed due to policy. Might [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-adsense) help you.

Comment: Put them in the `<head>` of your base HTML document.

Comment: I tried to use this plugin but i can not get it working, when I import it i get the following error

Comment: * !!babel-loader!../../selfie-lottery/client/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./VueAdsense.vue in /Users/jameslewis/Projects/~/vue-adsense/VueAdsense.vue
* vue-hot-reload-api in /Users/jameslewis/Projects/~/vue-adsense/VueAdsense.vue, ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-4c15f502"}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!/Users/jameslewis/Projects/~/vue-adsense/VueAdsense.vue
* vue in /Users/jameslewis/Projects/~/vue-adsense/VueAdsense.vue

Comment: james, were you ever able to find a solution to this as I ran into the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying the index.html file instead of the *.vue files. The Vue SPA app automatically listens for updates to *.vue files. So pasting the snippet in html file will bypass the compiler checks for undefined variables, etc.